# Uservoice updating an article doesn't work

Tags: ruby, uservoice

I'm writing to Uservoice articles via API. I write using following code:

```
    data = {
      :article =>
        {
          :question => question_name,
          :answer_html => html,
          :published => true
        }
    }

    site = "http://myapp.uservoice.com"

    puts "Remote site = #{site}"
    consumer = OAuth::Consumer.new(APP_CONFIG["uservoice"]["key"],
      APP_CONFIG["uservoice"]["secret"],
      {:site => site})

    accesstoken = OAuth::AccessToken.new(consumer,
     user.helpdesk["uservoice"]["oauth_token"],
     user.helpdesk["uservoice"]["oauth_token_secret"])

    response = JSON.parse(accesstoken.post("/api/v1/articles.json", data).body)
    flow.uservoice_id = response['article']['id']
    flow.save!
    puts "Save successful at #{response['article']['url']}"
```

This works. But when I want to do an update i.e `PUT`,

```
    response = JSON.parse(accesstoken.put("/api/v1/articles/#{article_id}.json", data))
```

I get a

`{"errors"=>{"type"=>"unauthorized", "message"=>"Admin required: Not signed or not admin. Unverified; Signature verification failed; User not signed: oauthenticate failed"}}`

As response. I am an admin as well. Writing (POST) works, but updating doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to log in as an admin (or owner).

```
accesstoken.login_as_owner do |owner|
  posted_response = owner.post("/api/v1/articles/#{article_id}.json", data)
end
```

Look the section "**Get the access token of the account owner and post responses**" at https://developer.uservoice.com/docs/api/ruby-sdk/